# 2D Arrays In Java - Not Printing

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
String[][] arrays = {
        {"Hello","World","Matt"},
        {"Computer","Good","Keyboard","Mouse"}
    };
    for(int r = 0; r < arrays.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < arrays[0].length; c++)
        {
            System.out.print(arrays[r][c]);
        }
    }
```

The result that I am getting from this is "HelloWorldMattComputerGoodKeyboard" where Mouse is not being included in this array.

Answer (score 3):

The rows of your array don't have the same length. Change your loop to  :

```
for(int r = 0; r < arrays.length; r++)
{
    for(int c = 0; c < arrays[r].length; c++)
    {
        System.out.print(arrays[r][c]);
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, my teacher used arrays[0].length as his example for creating 'rectangular' 2D arrays. Thanks for the fast response.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem in your inner loop where you are iterating 0 indexed array length every time, your 0th indexed arrays length is 3 that's why your mouse is not printing because your 2nd array's length is 4 ,try replacing `0` with `r` inside nested loop.

```
for(int r = 0; r < arrays.length; r++)
    {
        for(int c = 0; c < arrays[r].length; c++)
        {
            System.out.print(arrays[r][c]);
        }
    }
```